# Изменение параметров групповой политики через PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server

Суть такова:

1. Вношу изменения в "Default Domain Controllers Policy"

   ```
   Set-GPRegistryValue -Name "Default Domain Controllers Policy" -Key "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\KDC\Parameters" -ValueName "EnableCbacAndArmor" -Type DWord -Value 1
   Set-GPRegistryValue -Name "Default Domain Controllers Policy" -Key "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\KDC\Parameters" -ValueName "CbacAndArmorLeve" -Type DWord -Value 1
   ```
2. Создал один объект групповой политики "DAC Policy" через PS

   ```
    New-GPO -Name "DAC policy" | New-GPLink -Target "dc=test,dc=com" -LinkEnabled Yes | Set-GPPermission -TargetType User -TargetName "Admin" -PermissionLevel GpoEditDeleteModifySecurity
    Set-GPRegistryValue -Name "DAC Policy" -Key "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\KDC\Parameters" -ValueName "CbacAndArmorLeve" -Type DWord -Value 1
   ```

Следующим шагом хочу изменить параметр "DAC Policy", который отвечает за присоединение к этой политике доступных централизованных правил доступа, но в реестре не могу найти ветку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]